# How can I download the changesets from a visualforce page into a zip file?

Tags: visualforce, change-set, access

I am trying to download the changesets into a zip file from the visualforce page. But I feel like I am dumbstruck with no possibility of doing it. Can someone help me in doing it?

Comment: There is really no way to do this without using java/ant. However there is a tool called Gearset that allows you to download depoyements in a zip file. I just recently started using it, and it has tons of other bells and whistles as well.

Answer (score 2):

It seems, we can not able to import/export changesets to zip files.

There is an [Idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000l6F7AAI) for this on IdeaExchange

Answer (score 0):

Try out this chrome extension which helps you download package.xml of a changeset. Later you can use this package.xml to extract ZIP (source) using ANT or any metadata api tool.

> https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/download-salesforce-chang/olkmefomaellbafiabkljcemiljkkbeh

Comment: I thought this would do what I need - but looking at the reviews, it seems to have a lot of issues and no recent reviews confirming it's all working as expected

Comment: it's working for standard scenarios and complex changeset it's probably failing as metadata name/API etc isn't available, hence the extension is not able to support the same unless we update the extension to do metadata API to SF and fetch all of that information. Do try out, I'll say :)